# Booting a cloned VirtualBox VM on a different host

Tags: boot, virtualbox, transfer

I have cloned a VirtualBox machine, which runs Ubuntu.

I now wish to transfer it to a new host machine running Windows Vista 32-bit. I've
transferred the .vdi file and adjusted the name and memory. However when I boot it, it seems to be taking a long time. Is this usual? Or is something not working?

It says it's running but the screen is black and the SATA controller is just standing still.

Comment: Also, the VirtualMachine on my new host machine is newly installed so I have nothing there. Should I download Ubuntu before booting my cloned .vdi?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific on a couple of points: Original HOST, what you mean specifically by "clone", and did you just create a new virtual machine configuration and attached your existing hard drive or something a bit more involved in transporting the VM?

Comment: I made a clone of a VirtualMachine (on desktop) and now I am trying to transfer that to a new host machine (laptop) so I can work from there. I followed the specific procedures for cloning, such as using the clonehd from the command prompt.

Comment: In the past I have taken VB guest disk images on USB stick to another location and attached them to a new configuation as Goyuix mentioned and they just worked.

Comment: Well, I tested the clone version on the original machine and it booted fine but on my desktop when it was booting, options to choose the Linux version came up: Ubuntu, with Linux 2.6.38-10-generic, Linux 2.6.38-10-generic(recovery mode) , Previous Linux versions, Memory test.

Comment: Should I download Ubuntu to the IDE port?

Comment: On the Vista machine, try creating a new virtual machine with no hard disk, and attaching the cloned disk to it. Sometimes the .vbox vm "description" file becomes corrupted and fails to run properly. The .vbox file is an xml file, and can be viewed with a text editor.

Comment: Still giving me the same problem. Should I upload the Ubuntu .iso to IDE controller?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the .vdi is not fragmented on your host system and the memory is not too small for Ubuntu to run (512MB at least, 1GB + swap if you want to use Firefox or libre office).

Also make sure your host OS have enough free **physical** memory to run the virtual machine. You can find the number using Task Manager or similar tools. You should leave at least 400MB "free" physical memory after the virtual machine is loaded to allow the system to handle other application's spot memory use.

Comment: I have over a 100GB in my local disk. As for for .vdi, it says it has 4.61 GB as actual size and 7.79 GB as virtual size. However, the base memory for my VirtualMachine only goes up to 3072 MB. Could that be the problem? Also, since my VirtualMachine is newly installed, should I install Ubuntu as IDE controller? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice you are using a 32-bit host system, which means the whole OS can only recognize ~3GB of physical memory, so you're probably having a memory shortage. Trying closing non-essential programs and reducing the memory of the VM to ~1GB and see if it works better. Otherwise upgrade to a 64-bit OS.